# Migrate Wordpress content to Sitefinity

Tags: wordpress, sitefinity

I need to move posts (just posts, no pages) from Wordpress to Sitefinity. It seems simple enough to move the content from one table to another, but there's a great deal of image assets and I would also like to preserve the meta data, etc.

Short of writing a complex migration tool myself or manually moving nearly 200 posts, I found [this tool](https://github.com/timw255/WordPressToSitefinity) which helps in theory, but it is old (3 years from last update) and there's no instructions on what to do with it once the code is downloaded.

Does anyone have a better resource or a tried and true procedure for such a migration?

Comment: ###What to do first

All authors must already have accounts created in Sitefinity All custom blog post fields (meta data, related content, etc.) must be created prior to the import

###Copying the source files

Merge the source files into your project.

##Running the import

Make sure to do a backup of your project (including the database!) before attempting the import. Just in case, ya know. :)

Navigate to ~/Migration/WPM.aspx to upload your WordPress XML dump and select the options you'd like.
Click 'Run'

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this 'plugin' put together by TimW255?

https://github.com/timw255/WordPressToSitefinity

You will want to fork it and update the packages to your version of Sitefinity.